# photo color differs when viewing on chrome vs Picasa 3

Tags: canon, picasa, image-review

I had downloaded a photo taken with a Canon camera from the web. The photo color quality looks different when viewing in Chrome and in Picasa. In Chrome it seems to be the original tack sharp image with the exact details on it, but Picasa seems to be normalizing the colours.

Please check the uploaded screenshot of the photos on viewing Chrome/Picasa. 
Chrome - left, Picasa - Right.

Comment: So where is the uploaded screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

Picasa does an often-irritating "auto enhance" of pictures.  You are probably seeing the effects of that.  Here are instructions for turning off that feature: http://sites.google.com/site/picasaresources/Home/Picasa-FAQ/picasa-webalbums/how-to-articles/how-to-disable-auto-enhance